# Bootstrap carousel navigation is not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, carousel

a while ago i was working on bootstrap carousel, which has represents properties thumbnails based on offices and houses respectively.

entire function goes fine but the carousel navigation is not working.

**Here is HTML code**

```
<div class="container-fluid">
<div class="row-fluid">
<div class="span12" id="work_hider">

    <div class="page-header">
        <h2 class="pull-left"><?php if($this->lang->line('work') != '') { echo stripslashes($this->lang->line('work')); } else echo "Work"; ?></h2>
        <h3 class="pull-right" id="geolocate_work"></h3>
        <script>
            $.getJSON("https://freegeoip.net/json/", function(data) {
              var country = data.country_name;
              var city = data.city;

              $("#geolocate_work").html("<a href='property?city="+city+"'><?php if($this->lang->line('see_all') != '') { echo stripslashes($this->lang->line('see_all')); } else echo "See All"; ?></a>");

  jQuery.ajax({
               type:'POST',
               url:'<?php echo base_url("site/landing/get_work_places"); ?>',
               data:{ city_name:city},
               dataType: 'json', 

               success:function(data)
               {
                       var ParsedObject = JSON.stringify(data);  

                         var json = $.parseJSON(ParsedObject);

                   if (json=="")
                   {
                      $('#work_hider').hide();


                   }else
                   {


                       $.each(json, function(key, data) 
                         {
                           // All the variables from the database containing the post data.
                              var product_id=data.product_id;
                              var product_name=data.product_title;
                               var product_image=data.product_image;
                               var work_price = data.price_perhour;
                               var work_address = data.address;


                             $("#work-carousel").append('<li class="span3"><div class="thumbnail"><a href="<?php echo base_url('rental'); ?>/'+product_id+'"><img src="'+product_image+'" alt=""></a></div><div class="caption"><h2>'+work_price+'</h2></div><div class="caption"><h4>'+product_name+'</h4>  <p>'+work_address+'</p></div></li>');



                          });

                        for (i = 0; i <= 1; i++) {
                        $('.span3').slice(i * 4, (i + 1) * 4).wrapAll('<div class="item"><ul id="work_property">');

                      }


                  }
               }
              });


            });



        </script>

    </div>

    <div class="work_carousel slide" id="myCarousel">
        <div class="carousel-inner" id="work-carousel">
            <div class="item active" style="height: 100% !important;">
                    <ul class="thumbnails" id="work_property">


                    </ul>
              </div>


        </div>

        <div class="control-box" style="margin-bottom: 2em;">                            
            <a data-slide="prev" href="#myCarousel" class="carousel-control left">‹</a>
            <a data-slide="next" href="#myCarousel" class="carousel-control right">›</a>
        </div>

    </div>

</div>      
</div>
</div>
```

**Here is my carousel JS**

```
<script>
    var totalItems = $('.item').length;
    var currentIndex = $('div.active').index() + 1;
    $('.num').html(''+currentIndex+'/'+totalItems+'');

    $('.work_carousel').carousel({
        interval: 2000
    });

    $('.work_carousel').on('slide.bs.carousel', function() {
        currentIndex = $('div.active').index() + 1;

         if(currentIndex >= 2){

      $('#work_property').attr("id")="newid";

       }
    });
</script>
```

I've searched around a lot but i can't fix it. Does someone has a suggestion for me? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Looks like: $('#work_property').attr("id")="newid"; is assigning a value to the wrong element.

Comment: then, how can i fix it?

Comment: got it Mr. @Gerard. but how can i prevent automatically slides after runs 2 slides? do you have any suggestions?

Comment: All you say is that the carousel navigation is not working. Can you be more specific? Does the code break? is the functionality not correct? It would be helpful to get a link to a working example because the CSS is missing here or use snippets to create one yourself.

Comment: in this carousal code, i'm stop the slides after 2 slides by changing id. its working but it affect on navigation also :(